# displaying database records in unordered list format

Tags: php

I want to display my database records in `<ul> <li>` format. I have using a free template to design my front end. I am reading database data like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $categoryname = $row['category_name'];
}
```

and within the loop i have to display records like this

```
<li class="odd"><a href="services.html">Processors</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="services.html">Motherboards</a></li>
        <li class="odd"><a href="1_service.html">Processors</a></li>
        <li class="even"><a href="2_services.html">Motherboards</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="3_services.html">Desktops</a></li>
        <li class="even"><a href="4_services.html">Laptops & Notebooks</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="5_services.html">Processors</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="6_services.html">Motherboards</a></li>
        </ul>
```

How to do like this. Please suggest

if i want to give seperate page link to each lik like this

```
<li class="odd"><a href="services.html">Processors</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="services.html">Motherboards</a></li>
        <li class="odd"><a href="services.html">Processors</a></li>
        <li class="even"><a href="services.html">Motherboards</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="services.html">Desktops</a></li>
        <li class="even"><a href="services.html">Laptops & Notebooks</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="services.html">Processors</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="services.html">Motherboards</a></li>
        </ul>
```

then how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to watch the iteration to tell if you're on an even or odd cycle:

```
$output  = "";
$counter = -1;

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
  $class = $counter++ % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd" ;
  $href  = $row["category_url"];
  $text  = $row["category_name"];
  $output .= "<li class='{$class}'><a href='foo?id={$href}'>{$text}</a></li>";
}

echo "<ul>{$output}</ul>";
```

#### Native CSS Solution

Determining which elements are odd, and which are even is something that doesn't necessarily need to be done with PHP. In fact, it doesn't really require adding a classname to style each list item. CSS has a fancy selector, `:nth-child(n)`, that can handle this for you:

```
li:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    color: #CCC;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rquXK/

This means you can avoid determining the value of `$class`, and move that logic instead to your CSS. Just keep in mind that some older browsers won't support the feature.

Support Tables: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: Thank you very very much. It worked for me!. But if i want to ive separate link for each category, how i should change it?

Comment: Actually my href will be like this href='productscatalog?id=', can i pass this in $href  = $row["category_url"];
?

Comment: @user1321271 `"foo?id={$href}"`, where `$href` is `$_row["category_url"]`.

Comment: Perhaps you can let the users browser do the calculation, not your code on the server. Additionally write it once inside the CSS so you can change it later on for your whole application w/o changing PHP template code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10812123/367456

Comment: @hakre Good suggestion. I've amended my answer above.

Comment: @  Jonathan Sampson: please have a look into my code, which i have edited. if i want to do like that, how can i?

Comment: @user1321271 Do what? Can you be more specific?

Comment: instead of giving like to a common page, i want to give each li likn to different page.

Comment: @user1321271 How do you know the page you want to link to? Is it stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo '<li class="'.($i++ % 2 == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even').'">'.$row['category_name'].'</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$index = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $className = ($index %2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd" ;
    $categoryName = $row['category_name'];
?>

<li class="<?php echo $className;?>"><a href="services.html"><?php echo $categoryName;?> </a></li>

<?php 
  $index++
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a counter, increment it in the loop, and if it's an odd number set class to odd, if even set class to even. So based on @bsdnoobz answer:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $class = $i % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
    echo "<li class='$class'>".$row['category_name'].'</li>';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parentid = 0; // assuming that 0 is the main category.

get_sub_cats($parentid);

function get_sub_cats($parentid) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE parent_id = ".$parentid.""; 
    $run = mysql_query($sql);

    echo '<ul>';

    while ($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) { 
        echo '<li />'.$rec['study']; 
        get_sub_cats($rec['id']);
    }

    echo '</ul>';

}
```

Hope it works....

Answer (score 0):

Using the `class` attribute to signal even or odd rows/entries suggests that you're making use of CSS to style those.

Depending on which browser you still need to support, this might be necessary. However, normally it is not any longer:

> *Warning:* at the time of writing (February 2003), the major browsers don't yet support the 'nth-child' selector (introduced in November 2001)

http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

CSS Example:

```
li:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
li:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

See [CSS: Even And Odd Rules](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html)